# sparse hstack and weird dtype conversion error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In working with some text data, I'm trying to join an np array(from a pandas series) to a csr matrix.

I've done the below.

```
#create a compatible sparse matrix from my np.array.
#sparse.csr_matrix(X['link'].values) returns array size (1,7395)
#transpose that array for (7395,1)

X = sparse.csr_matrix(X['link'].values.transpose)


#bodies is a sparse.csr_matrix with shape (7395, 20000)

bodies = sparse.hstack((bodies,X))
```

However, this line gives the error `no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)`. I'm not sure what this means? How do I get around it?

Thanks.

Comment: When must call transpose, call it like `.transpose()` or `.T` otherwise you are actually passing the function object to create the array giving the verified object type...

Comment: Once again, I am appalled by how bad the numpy docs are. I've had no luck creating a sparse array of strings, or duplicating your error. According to google, you are the first person to ever encounter that error.

Comment: working on StumbleUpon data set in Kaggle? :) I faced the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's  Saullo Castro's comment cast as an answer:

```
x = np.arange(12).reshape(1,12)  # ndarray
sparse.csr_matrix(x)
Out[14]: <1x12 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

x.transpose   # function, not ndarray
Out[15]: <function transpose>  

X = sparse.csr_matrix(x.transpose)
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)
```

The error occurs before using `hstack`, trying to make a sparse matrix from a function rather than an ndarray.  The error was omitting the `()`.

```
# x.transpose() == x.T   # ndarray

sparse.csr_matrix(x.transpose())
Out[17]: <12x1 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

sparse.csr_matrix(x.T)
Out[18]: <12x1 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>


bodies = sparse.rand(12,3,format='csr',density=.1)
sparse.hstack((bodies,X))
Out[32]: <12x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 14 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

`csr_matrix` works fine if it is given the transposed array.

Comment: thanks you, I was at the mobile to post such an explanatory answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse

d = {
    "a": 30,
    "b": 20,
    "c": 10
}

s = pd.Series(d, index=["c", "b", "a"])
print s

--output:--
c    10
b    20
a    30
dtype: int64

my_ndarray = s.values
print my_ndarray

--output:--
[10 20 30]

X = sparse.csr_matrix(my_ndarray).transpose()
print X.todense()

--output:--
[[10]
 [20]
 [30]]


bodies = sparse.csr_matrix([
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 0]
])
print bodies.todense()

--output:--
[[0 1]
 [1 0]
 [0 0]]

result = sparse.hstack((bodies,X))  
print result.todense()

--output:--
[[ 0  1 10]
 [ 1  0 20]
 [ 0  0 30]]
```

And writing:

```
X = sparse.csr_matrix(my_ndarray.transpose())
```

produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 33, in <module>
    result = sparse.hstack((bodies,X))  
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 417, in hstack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 515, in bmat
    raise ValueError('blocks[%d,:] has incompatible row dimensions' % i)
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
```

Compare to:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse

d = {
    "a": "hello",
    "b": "world",
    "c": "goodbye"
}

s = pd.Series(d, index=["c", "b", "a"])
print s

--output:--
c    goodbye
b      world
a      hello

my_ndarray = s.values
print my_ndarray

--output:--
[goodbye world hello]

X = sparse.csr_matrix(s.values).transpose()

--output:--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 19, in <module>
    X = sparse.csr_matrix(s.values).transpose()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 66, in __init__
    self._set_self( self.__class__(coo_matrix(arg1, dtype=dtype)) )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 30, in __init__
    arg1 = arg1.asformat(self.format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 203, in asformat
    return getattr(self,'to' + format)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 312, in tocsr
    data    = np.empty(self.nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py", line 53, in upcast
    raise TypeError('no supported conversion for types: %r' % (args,))
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('object'),)
```

The fact that you didn't provide examples like this yourself means you did not put enough work into debugging the problem.

Comment: This answer is going off on a rabbit trail.  You are using `transpose()`, not `transpose` as in the question.

Comment: @hpaulj, A pandas Series has a value attribute, which returns an ndarray. An ndarray does not have a transpose attribute, but it does have a transpose() method; and as far as I can tell from the docs, the sparse.csr_matrix() method does not take a method as an argument. However, feel free to post a link which describes ndarray's transpose attribute, or a link describing how csr_matrix() takes a method from another class as an argument. That's the trail the op made--I don't know if they were chasing rabbits or not.